# NLTK ChartParser giving empty list

Tags: python, nltk

The task is to define a grammar and use a ChartParser to parse any given sentence using the ChartParser package in nltk. My code is as follows:

```
import nltk

your_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
NP -> NP PP
Nom ->  N
VP -> V NP | V S | VP PP
PP -> P NP
Det -> 'the' 
N -> 'block' | 'table' 
V -> 'Put'
P -> 'on' 
""")

parser = nltk.ChartParser(your_grammar)
sent = 'Put the block on the table'.split()
print (list(parser.parse(sent)))
```

But the output gives an empty list.

The output:

```
[]
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: There's some issues with the grammar. If I partially expand the start, I get `NP 'on' NP VP` and since `NP -> NP` it is not possible to resolve it to "nothing"; I have to always match something else. Since this is not possible, the grammar does not work. If `NP -> ''` then that will allow `NP` to not be matched (good), which will therefore imply `S -> VP` which will start matching the first word `Put`

Comment: @alexyorke Thank you for the input. I went through the grammar again and tried to manually parse the sentence as you said. To rectify the problems, i added the following rules as well: S->VP NP,VP->V,NP->Det N. And now it seems to work!

Comment: Great! I just posted my comment as an answer, feel free to accept to let others know how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the grammar cannot match any string because it contains an infinite loop.

If I partially expand `S`, I get `NP 'on' NP VP` and since `NP -> NP` it is not possible to resolve it to "nothing"; I have to always match something else.

If `NP -> ''` then that will allow NP to not be matched (good), which will therefore imply `S -> VP` which will start matching the first word `Put`. This should put the grammar on the right track, depending on how you want it to match.